# transform into 1D arraylist from 2D arraylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Hey guys this is reverted thing from my previous question. Not solved yet. but making the simple requirement that i need a code that will do convert my 2D array into 1D array with an condition. i.e.

```
A[0,2,3,7,0,0,5,3][0,2,2,4,0,0,3,0]
```

and i want this as result

```
B[2,2,4,3,0]
```

This does mean i want those values which are not zero from 2D array's second colum.

**"Please note that the numbers are the length of particular array."**

Comment: your first array is not a valid 2d array

Comment: I dont know even this is possible or not ... is it phisible ??

Comment: why ?? i can take two array also

Comment: Just like A[0,2,3,7,0,0,5,3] and B[0,2,2,4,0,0,3,0]

Comment: can you write your input value and required output value in the form of valid javascript, at least then I'll see why my answer on your previous question isn't correct, even though it produces the required output

Comment: *the numbers are the length of particular array* ... which array**S** are they the length of (I assume you mean arrays not array, otherwise you're saying that a *particular array* has several different lengths at once ... which is unpossible

Comment: yes u assumed right ... its arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkBox = [Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4, Array5, Array6];
var dataOfUS = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6];

for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < checkBox.length, j < dataOfUS.length; i++) {
if (checkBox[i].length > 0) {
                    arrays[k] = dataOfUS[j];
                    k++;
                }
                j++;
            }
```

Try this might work surely, i hope......

Comment: this is seriously working man .... perfecto to merge the array in 1D with condition